# Accessing an app via heroku domain when it's set to a custom domain

Tags: heroku

I have an app with a custom domain that I'm letting retire.
I'd like to keep the custom domain until it expires but give people the ability to access the app via the heroku domain already so they can get used to it, but when I go to the address specified in my app, it says no app is found.

Is it invisible because of the custom domain? Is there another way to expose the heroku domain to the world?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: where/how are you setting up this custom domain?

Comment: This is strange because my app is accessible via custom domain and Heroku domain.

Comment: I'm doing it at Settings -> Domains, this is the address my custom domain is pointing to: pure-chimpanzee-yqwbg0g75xf3q4prm8ww0hx9.herokudns.com so far as I can tell, it's unavailable to the world

Comment: https://help.heroku.com/3EUIOIVB/why-can-t-i-access-herokudns-com-cname-endpoints-in-my-browser this is probably why, question is.. how do I find my .herokuapp.com address?